# How to solve "message truncated: error stack" error in MPI c program?

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to make a C program that reads two matrices (A and B) of variable size, from 2 different .csv files, and then prints their multiplication (A*B), matrix C. I'm using MPI, since this program has to run in a headless Raspberry Pi cluster (using Raspbian Stretch Lite) . The idea is that the master node sends each worker node some rows of matrix A and all of matrix B, so that each worker does a partial multiplication simultaneously. Then, all the resulting parts must be united to form matrix C, which is printed on screen. When I run it in the cluster, I get a message truncation error.

The problem occurs when the worker nodes receive their part of matrix A. I'm new to mpi programming, but what understand from the error message I get is that the number of data elements expected (int) is 0. I don't know why this happens, since in the MPI_RECV routine I specify the correct number of data elements, which is the number of rows of A assigned to each worker times the number of columns of the matrix A.

This is the part where data is sent:

```
/* send matrix data to the worker tasks */  
   rows = fa/numworkers;  //fa is the total number of rows in A
   offset = 0;  
   remainPart = fa%numworkers;  
   printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",fa,ca,fb,cb);
   for (dest=1; dest<=numworkers; dest++)   
   {          
    if (remainPart > 0)  
    {      
      originalRows = rows;  
      ++rows;  //rows=3
      remainPart--;  //remain=1
      MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
      MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
      MPI_Send(&A[offset][0], rows * ca, MPI_INT,dest,3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
      MPI_Send(&B, fb * cb, MPI_INT, dest, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
      offset = offset + rows;   
      rows = originalRows; 
      printf("Sending rows...\n");
    }  
    else  
    {      
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        MPI_Send(&A[offset][0], rows * ca, MPI_INT,dest,3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        MPI_Send(&B, fb * cb, MPI_INT, dest, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        offset = offset + rows;  
        printf("Sending rows...\n");
    }  
   }
```

And this is the part where the data is received:

```
if (taskid > 0) {  
    printf("receiving...\n");
   source = 0;  
   MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
   MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
   MPI_Recv(&A, rows * ca, MPI_INT, source, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
   MPI_Recv(&B, fb * cb, MPI_INT, source, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
   /* Matrix multiplication */  
   for (k=0; k<cb; k++)  
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {  
     C[i][k] = 0;  
     for (j=0; j<ca; j++)  
      C[i][k] = C[i][k] + A[i][j] * B[j][k];  
    }  
   MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
   MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 6, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
   MPI_Send(&C, rows * ca, MPI_INT, 0, 7, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
  }
```

I don't know if this is relevant or not in this error, but here is part of the function where matrices A and B are created:

```
//sizex is the number of rows, and sizey is the number of columns. 
int** makemat(int sizex,int sizey, FILE *fp)
{
    int conti;
    int contj;
    int** matrix;
    matrix=(int**)malloc(sizex*sizeof(int*));
    for(conti=0; conti<sizex; conti++)
    {
        matrix[conti]=(int*)malloc(sizey*sizeof(int));
    }
...

return(matrix);
   }
```

Here is the error message:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Recv: Message truncated, error stack:
PMPI_Recv(171)......................: MPI_Recv(buf=0x23098, count=0, MPI_INT, src=0, tag=3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status=0x230b4) failed
MPIDI_CH3U_Request_unpack_uebuf(516): Message truncated; 12 bytes received but buffer size is 0
Fatal error in PMPI_Recv: Message truncated, error stack:
PMPI_Recv(171)......................: MPI_Recv(buf=0x23098, count=0, MPI_INT, src=0, tag=3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status=0x230b4) failed
MPIDI_CH3U_Request_unpack_uebuf(516): Message truncated; 12 bytes received but buffer size is 0
```

I know for a fact matrices A and B are saved correctly, since the program prints them every time I run it, right before the error.
Thanks in advance for any help. If you want to see the full code, please comment, and I'll add it.

Update:
The following code is the minimal reproducible example I made.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>



 MPI_Status status;  
 main(int argc, char **argv)   
 {  
  int numtasks,taskid,numworkers,source,dest,rows,offset,i,j,k,remainPart,originalRows; 
  size_t rowsa,colsa,rowsb,colsb; 
  struct timeval start, stop;  
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);  
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);  
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);  
  numworkers = numtasks-1;  
  /*---------------------------- master ----------------------------*/  
  if (taskid == 0) {

   //matrix A is generated and printed. In the original code, this would be done with 2 functions 
   //(Fcounter,makemat)
   puts("Rows A?");
   scanf("%ld",&rowsa);
   puts("Cols A?");
   scanf("%ld",&colsa);

   //A=(int**)malloc(rowsa*sizeof(int*));
   //for (i=0;i<rowsa;i++){
    //A[i]=(int*)malloc(colsa*sizeof(int));
   //}
   int* A=malloc(sizeof *A *rowsa *colsa);
   for(i=0;i<rowsa;i++){
    for(j=0;j<colsa;j++){
        A[i*rowsa+j]=2+i+j;
        printf("%d\t",A[i*rowsa+j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
   }

   //matrix B is generated and printed. In the original code, this would be done with 2 functions 
   //(Fcounter,makemat)
   puts("Rows B?");
   scanf("%ld",&rowsb);
   puts("Cols B?");
   scanf("%ld",&colsb);

   int* B=malloc(sizeof *B *rowsb *colsb);
   //B=(int**)malloc(rowsb*sizeof(int*));
   //for (i=0;i<rowsb;i++){
    //B[i]=(int*)malloc(colsb*sizeof(int));
   //}
   for(i=0;i<rowsb;i++){
    for(j=0;j<colsb;j++){
        B[i*rowsb+j]=2+(i*j);
        printf("%d\t",B[i*rowsb+j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
   }




   gettimeofday(&start, 0);  
   /* send matrix data to the worker tasks */  
   rows = rowsa/numworkers;  
   offset = 0;  
   remainPart = rowsa%numworkers;  
   for (dest=1; dest<=numworkers; dest++)  //in this part, each worker is assigned some of A's rows 
   {          
    if (remainPart > 0)  
    {      
      originalRows = rows;  
      ++rows;  
      remainPart--;
      MPI_Send(&rowsa, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 5,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&colsa, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 6,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&rowsb, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 7,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      MPI_Send(&colsb, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 8,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
      MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
      MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
      MPI_Send(&A[offset*rowsa+0], rows*colsa, MPI_INT,dest,3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
      MPI_Send(&B, rowsb*colsb, MPI_INT, dest, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
      offset = offset + rows;   
      rows = originalRows;  
    }  
    else  
    {   
        MPI_Send(&rowsa, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 5,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&colsa, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 6,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&rowsb, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 7,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&colsb, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 8,MPI_COMM_WORLD);   
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        MPI_Send(&A[offset*rowsa+0], rows*colsa, MPI_INT,dest,3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        MPI_Send(&B, rowsb*colsb, MPI_INT, dest, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
        offset = offset + rows;  
    }  
   } 




   /* wait for results from all worker tasks */  
   for (i=1; i<=numworkers; i++) //master "gathers" all the parts of C and prints the whole array     
   {              
    source = i;
    //printf("ARRIBA");
    int* C=malloc(sizeof *C *rowsa *colsb);  
    MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, 9, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
    MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
    MPI_Recv(&C[offset*rowsa+0], rows*colsb, MPI_INT, source, 11, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
   } 
   int* C=malloc(sizeof *C *rowsa *colsb); 
   gettimeofday(&stop, 0);  
    printf("Here is the result matrix:\n");  //resulting matrix has rowsa rows and colsb columns
   for (i=0; i<rowsa; i++) {   
    for (j=0; j<colsb; j++)   
     printf("%d\t", C[i*rowsa+j]);  
    printf ("\n");  
   }  



   fprintf(stdout,"Time = %.6f\n\n",  
      (stop.tv_sec+stop.tv_usec*1e-6)-(start.tv_sec+start.tv_usec*1e-6));  
  } 

   int* C=malloc(sizeof *C *rowsa *colsb);
   //C=(int**)malloc(rowsa*sizeof(int*));
   //for(i=0;i<rowsa;i++){
    //C[i]=(int*)malloc(colsb*sizeof(int));
    //} 
  /*---------------------------- worker----------------------------*/  
  if (taskid > 0) {  //in this part, all the partial multiplications are done. condition: colsa=rowsb
   source = 0;

   int* A=malloc(sizeof *A *rowsa *colsa);
   int* B=malloc(sizeof *B *rowsb *colsb); 
   int* C=malloc(sizeof *C *rowsa *colsb);

   MPI_Recv(&rowsa, 1,MPI_INT, source, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
   MPI_Recv(&colsa, 1,MPI_INT, source, 6, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
   MPI_Recv(&rowsb, 1,MPI_INT, source, 7, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
   MPI_Recv(&colsb, 1,MPI_INT, source, 8, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
   MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
   MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
   printf("rows: %d, colsa: %ld, rowsb: %ld, colsb: %ld\n",rows,colsa,rowsb,colsb);
   MPI_Recv(&A, rows*colsa, MPI_INT, source, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  
   MPI_Recv(&B, rowsb*colsb, MPI_INT, source, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);  

   /* Matrix multiplication */  
   for (k=0; k<colsb; k++)  
    for (i=0; i<rowsa; i++) {  
     C[i*rowsa+j] = 0;  
     for (j=0; j<colsa; j++)  
      C[i*rowsa+k] = C[i*rowsa+k] + A[i*rowsa+j] * B[j*rowsb+k];  
    }  
   MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 9, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
   MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
   MPI_Send(&C, rowsa*colsb, MPI_INT, 0, 11, MPI_COMM_WORLD);  
  }   
  MPI_Finalize();  
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please always include a [MCVE]. You also have to allocate your arrays in contiguous memory.

Comment: Verify your `count` arguments to receive. The stack suggests that it's zero, but I don't know if that trace can be trusted.

Comment: Try with MPI_Recv(A, ... )  instead of MPI_Recv(&A, ... ). Since you are not providing explicit offset & is not required.

Comment: As a side note, this is a good opportunity to learn about `MPI_Bcast()` and `MPI_Scatterv()`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError First of all, thanks all of you for the comments and sorry that I took a while to answer, my cluster broke and I am currently setting it up again. So I checked the count arguments, it turns out they are 0. I print them at the moment of them being sent, and the values are correct, but at the moment of them being received, they are all equal to 0. Should I send the variables from the master node to the workers too? I tried doing that, and I just get a segmentation fault error. Right now the code is being compiled and ran on a desktop pc, not the cluster.

Comment: @j23 I tried that, and when I compile the code I get the following warning:
multimatrix2.c: In function ‘main’:
multimatrix2.c:139:16: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘MPI_Send’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       MPI_Send(A[offset][0], rows * ca, MPI_INT,dest,3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                ^
In file included from multimatrix2.c:2:0:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include/mpi.h:1702:20: note: expected ‘const void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 OMPI_DECLSPEC  int MPI_Send(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest,

Comment: @j23 Also, when running the program, I get the following error:
*** Process received signal ***
Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
Failing at address: 0x2f8
[ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20)[0x7fc940281f20]
[ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x18eae3)[0x7fc9403d1ae3]
[ 2] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-pal.so.20(opal_convertor_pack+0x196)[0x7fc93fd401c6]
[ 3] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_btl_vader.so(mca_btl_vader_sendi+0x4a2)[0x7fc92e925e12]

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet When you say i have to allocate the arrays in contiguous memory, do you mean I should do this: "int * arr = malloc(sizeof * arr * rows * cols);" instead of this "matrix=(int * * )malloc(sizex * sizeof(int * ));
    for(conti=0; conti<sizex; conti++)
    {
        matrix[conti]=(int * )malloc(sizey * sizeof(int));
    }" in the makemat function?

Comment: That’s the idea. There are numerous examples on SO.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Doing that gives me the same error.

Comment: the [MCVE] you posted works fine, right ? If so, then please post a [MCVE] that evidences the issue.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Ok so I updated my post and added an minimal reproducible example that gives me the same error as the original code.

Comment: I strongly advise you to compile with `-Wall` to detect and fix the use of uninitialized variables. Are you sure `MPI_INT` is the right type to communicate a `size_t` ? Note `MPI_Bcast()` is a great fit here.